# Is this eval Evil?

Tags: javascript, eval

Writing a function in JavaScript. The plan is the function creates an object, which requires boolean statements as parameters. Something like this ->

```
var foo = new fuzz("pie < squirrel", "monkey === banana");
```

My question is - Is this evil?

**Note - ** Inside the function 'fuzz' I will run checks on the values of the parameters. (Check string.length etc). I think this is how one is meant to use eval, it just has such a bad reputation on t'up web.

Thanks

Comment: Why not pass in those statements as anonymous functions?

Comment: The code you show as such is not. The code where you're actually using `eval` maybe not either per se. But maybe there's a better solution overall which doesn't need `eval` at all. We can't tell without more context.

Comment: Where does the values come from that are used in the boolean expressions? Is there any reason you can't just pass in boolean values?

Comment: Its part of a larger program, which is meant to be very 'dynamic'. I need to create a structure for creating buttons. The buttons change, depending on many many things. The number of boolean statements is unknown for each button. (For example button 'A' might have label 'B' if variable 'C < 4'... But it might also have value 'D' if 'C == 3'... That kind of thing. So the statements will be taken and used in if statements within the object. They will only ever be using in if statements. I will parse the statements (Check the length. Check theres no ";" and each one contains a bool operator.

Comment: Creating a simple rule evaluation engine seems more sensible. If you only need to support simple comparison operations, that's pretty trivial to implement. Parse the string into three parts, the left operand, the right operand and the operator, and `switch ()` based on the operator.

Comment: Should of mentioned the values come from an array of properties. They are returned through a function and not 'set' by the user. (User has no 'real' control of any of the values). The reason I want to use eval is for neatness of cold and look. It'll let future developers (Or me) add 'buttons' to the program by simply creating a new object in one of the files read into the main program.

Comment: I hadn't considered using a switch statement like that. Thanks Deceze! Think I'm going to try that now. If you wrote that up as a answer I'd accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summing up the conclusions in the comments: write a simple rule evaluation engine! E.g.:

```
var variables = { ... };

function niceEval(condition) {
    var operands = condition.match(/(\w+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\w+)/);

    switch (operands[2]) {
        case '<' :
            return variables[operands[1]] < variables[operands[3]];
        ...
    }
}
```

This also gives you a lot more control over possibly occurring errors than blindly `eval`ing a string.